# How do you extract N and E from a RSA public key in python?

Tags: python, cryptography, rsa, public-key, pycrypto

I have a RSA public key such that it looks like

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ0AMIIBCAKCAQEAvm0WYXg6mJc5GOWJ+5jk
htbBOe0gyTlujRER++cvKOxbIdg8So3mV1eASEHxqSnp5lGa8R9Pyxz3iaZpBCBB
vDB7Fbbe5koVTmt+K06o96ki1/4NbHGyRVL/x5fFiVuTVfmk+GZNakH5dXDq0fwv
JyVmUtGYAiMJWPni2hGpAsbyjzLix9UNX5XiYIIrIr55IHtD5u1XNkmYLOdVQ98r
6hez3t2eaE0pP2k+mjRach+2tD93PBZmreHgVZtejumi+ZWLMqpd++AY0AzH0m8E
6sa8JFUAiYZbVtmrcGTCUCkzC2Es1/knSeZ41xki1qD0V3uw/APP8Q+BgbX3SJp0
EQIBAw==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

I want to find out what the modulo N and exponent E are from this key, in python?

Using pycrypto package I am able to load to the key as such:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

# read the public key in:
public_key = RSA.importKey(open('key.pub', 'r').read())
```

but following the documentation of [pycrypto's rsa module](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.PublicKey.RSA-module.html) It wasn't clear how to extract the smaller components. How do I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After an hour or so of playing around and googling and not finding a solution here is the really simple solution. Which stems off of how python objects work.

When looking at the documentation, notice how it talks about the [keydata](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.PublicKey.RSA._RSAobj-class.html#keydata)

What this tells us that when we do

```
pub_key = RSA.importKey()
```

we are creating an RSAobject. this object has the variables

```
['n', 'e', 'd', 'p', 'q', 'u']
```

So you simply have to do:

```
print pub_key.n
print pub_key.e
```

and so on to access those variables from that object.

Answer (score 4):

For example if your public key is saved as alicepublic.pem in your directory:

```
>>>from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
>>>f = open("alicepublic.pem", "r")
>>>key = RSA.importKey(f.read())
>>>print key.n #displays n
>>>print key.e #displays e
```

Doing this in the interpreter will display the components.

to install Crypto use this:
`pip install pycryptodome`